# How to remove default <b></b> labels from Zend FormErrors

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm fairly new the Zend Framework and I'm stuck.

The following code is a snippet of my form's decorator setting where I'm experiencing a problem:

```
// prepend errors to top
$this->setDecorators(
    array(
        'FormElements',
        'Form',
        array(
            'FormErrors',
             array(
                'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::PREPEND
             )
         )
    )
);
```

When errors are rendered on the view I get the following:

```
    <ul class="form-errors">
       <li>
          <b>First Name: </b>
          <ul class="errors">
             <li>You forgot to enter your First Name.</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

How do you remove all of the html including the label `<b>First Name: </b>`?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/

Answer (score 2):

Just create custom decorator, try something like this

```
protected $_errorDecorator = array(
    'markupElementLabelEnd'   => '',
    'markupElementLabelStart' => '',
    'placement'=>Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::PREPEND
);

$this->setDecorators(array('FormElements','Form',
    array('FormErrors',
    $_errorDecorator)));
```

Comment: showing the link to the manual would be helpful for OP and future visitors of this website I guess ;)

Comment: I guess that's a start, however the label content "First Name:" still remains.  I was wondering how do I remove that as well

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party but since this is top 5 Google result, and still unanswered, I thought I'd contribute.

Best way is to extend Zend decorator, overload `renderLabel` method, add `renderLabels` config option and then just check if it's set. If so, don't call parent function which renders your label.

```
$form->setDecorators(
    array(
        'FormElements',
        'Form',
        array(
            'FormErrors',
             array(
                'placement' => 'prepend',
                'renderLabels' => false
             )
         )
    )
);

class My_Form_Decorator_FormErrors extends Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors
{
    /**
     * @see Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors::renderLabel()
     */
    public function renderLabel(Zend_Form_Element $element, Zend_View_Interface $view)
    {
        if ($this->getOption('renderLabels') === false) {
            return;
        }

        return parent::renderLabel($element, $view);
    }
}
```